# XPath query searching for an element with specific text

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML structure

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>Test: Text2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Test: Text3</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Test: Text5</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the best XPath query to locate any `span` with text that starts with `Test`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
//span[starts-with(.,'Test')]
```

References:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with

Comment: There's a good chance you'll want to normalize-space() on that too, making it `//span[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'Test')]`.

Answer (score 4):

Valid option is also:

```
//span[contains(.,'Test')]
```

Comment: That will yield even if "Test" is in the end of a string. Thus not an applicable solution.